# How to find the greatest number among 3 integer numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone explain to me where & how can I use this equation. I was told to make a program that reads 3 integer numbers and prints the greatest one using the following formula. But how?

$$\operatorname{Major} AB = \frac{a+b+abs(a-b)}{2}$$

Answer (score 7):

The equation you've given returns the maximum of two numbers; that is,

$$\max\{a, b\} = \frac{a + b + |a - b|}{2}$$

To see this, simply note that if $a \ge b$, we have

$$a + b + |a - b| = a + b + (a - b) = 2a$$

and if $a < b$,

$$a + b + |a - b| = a + b - (a - b) = 2b$$
Then to find the largest of *three* numbers, simply compare the first two, and then compare the result with the third number.

Answer (score 5):

This is the max function

$$ max(a,b) = \frac{(a+b) + |a-b|}{2}$$

So 
$$
\begin{align}
max(a,b,c) &= max(max(a,b),c) \\
&= \frac{max(a,b)+c+|max(a,b)-c|}{2}\\
&=\frac{\frac{(a+b) + |a-b|}{2}+c+|\frac{(a+b) + |a-b|}{2}-c|}{2}\
\end{align}
$$

But this is probably **not** what your instructor wants.

He probably wants you to use write the function and then use is twice. Since you do not specify the programming language, I will use the C language. Works with C++ also. You may have to change it a bit for Java.

\begin{verbatim}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int mx(int a, int b) {
     return (a+b+abs(a-b))/2;
}
void main() {
    int x,y,z,answer;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z); // or any other way to read 3 numbers
    answer=mx(a,b);
    answer=mx(answer, c);
    printf("Max of %d, %d, %d is %d\n", a, b, c, answer);
}
\end{verbatim}